# How do I make jQuery dropdown menus drop straight down instead of off to the right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a very simple menu bar that I made with jQuery, and it functions as expected, but I would really like the submenus to pop up directly underneath the main menu and not over to the right, as shown in this [jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/kgjac/)   Do you know any way that I can make this happen?  This is my first time using jQuery (and one of my first times using Javascript at all), so I'm a little bit lost.

Here is my css, which I believe may somehow be the problem, since the list is just plain HTML.

```
#menu-bar{
    height:30px;
    width: 100%;
}

#menu-bar > li{
    float:left;
    width:195px;
}
```

Comment: Does accordion work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/kgjac/6/

Comment: Accordion definitely works for me.  Is there any way I can make it so neither of them open by default?  Like, the file menu opens automatically, and I definitely don't want it to open automatically, and I'd like it to close when the user clicks off of it (like a regular menu bar)

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/kgjac/14/

Comment: Huh.  That's really nifty.  @Thomas showed me that I can pass a position to menu(), so I'll just be doing that, but thanks for the suggestion.  I'll definitely be using that in the future.

Comment: No worries I've done both before :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass some options, where your submenus should appear. Like this:

```
$( "#menu-bar" ).menu({ position: { my: "left top", at: "left bottom" } });
```

more on this topic: http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/#option-position

Comment: This is perfect.  As soon as I can accept your answer, I will.  Thanks for the extra info too, I don't know why I didn't check it.  That's always my first resort.

Comment: you're welcome. It is a bit weird that this is not included in the jqueryui examples page as many people certainly whish to do this.

Comment: Yeah, definitely.  I honestly didn't even realize how amazing the API documentation is.  I'll be bookmarking it.  I just assumed the examples page showed everything I needed to know.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
$( "#menu-bar" ).menu({ position: { my: "left top", at: "left bottom+2" } });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kgjac/10/

That is, by setting the [`position` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/#option-position) as specified in the [`.menu()` documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/).

Experiment with the `+2` part for yourself: you can tweak the position up or down by changing this number or leaving it (and the `+`) out altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest use the superfish menu.
http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#a

Comment: Is there any way you could send me a different link to that?  For some reason that link is blocked on my work firewall.

Comment: Check out the demo for the same jquery plugin at https://github.com/joeldbirch/superfish

Comment: Wow, that looks really nice.  I'm trying not to keep adding plugins to my site though.  I'm trying to keep it lightweight as possible.  Thanks for the suggestions though.  nnnnn and @Thomas figured it out without having to install other plugins.

Comment: Sorry posted the wrong link. Check the latest one, which is a link to github. I am working on getting a jsfiddle for the same.

Comment: @AlexKibler cool. Its always good to not rely on other plugins. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#menu-bar" ).menu({position: {my: "left top", at: "left bottom"}});
```

or adjust the position to wherever you want it.